# Cordova ES6 Module Support?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mime-types, es6-modules

I'm using Cordova with the Crosswalk plugin to provide a modern webview for android v4.1-4.4. ES6 features appear to be available within the Crosswalk webview as I can use the new let/const variables, classes, arrow functions etc.

My issue is that I can't seem to get `<script type="module">` working. I believe the issue is due to the local resources not being loaded with the `application/javascript` mime type. Is there any way to specify this mime type so that modules work in cordova? I'd prefer not to have to transpile to ES5 if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research it is now clear that the chromium version offered by Crosswalk does not have support for ES6 modules. You can add support for them using a polyfill which seems to work fine. I'm using the [es-module-loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader) which appears to support importing from the local `file://` uri's that Cordova uses. Other polyfills which utilise `fetch` do not support this.